# T-SQL Challenges from hackerrank

Tags: sql-server

Julia asked her students to create some coding challenges. Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude those students from the result.

Input Format

The following tables contain challenge data:

Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name of the hacker. 
[Hackers Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXVQ3.png)

Challenges: The challenge_id is the id of the challenge, and hacker_id is the id of the student who created the challenge. 
[Challenges Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuXnH.png)

here is the query that i wrote

```
select H.hacker_id,H.name,T.challenges_created 
from Hackers H  join 
(SELECT hacker_id , 
       COUNT(Challeneges.challenge_id) as challenges_created 
FROM  Challenges 
GROUP BY hacker_id
HAVING challenges_created >= max(challenges_created) 
) T
on H.hacker_id=T.hacker_id
ORDER BY T.challenges_created desc, H.hacker_id asc
```

but i'm getting error saying that

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 12  Invalid
>   column name 'challenges_created'.  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server
>   WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 12  Invalid column name 'challenges_created'. 
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 9  The
>   multi-part identifier "Challeneges.challenge_id" could not be bound.

Comment: `challenges_created` is a column alias, `HAVING` cannot recognize those.

Comment: so whats the best way to check the conditions on aggregate columns

Comment: Either repeat the actual column value in `HAVING`, or do `HAVING` outside of the sub-query. In the latter case `HAVING` will have no problems with the column name because it would be an actual column *in the subquery*

Comment: I can't use Having clause outside the sub query cause it would throw me an error, as you know i wanted perform aggregation on that column

Comment: You can always create one more subquery and use it outside of *that* subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Line 9 The multi-part identifier "Challeneges.challenge_id" could not be bound.
```

Looks like you spelt `Challenges` wrong.

Comment: thanks for the reply   i have just edited the code and  got the following error   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 12 
Invalid column name 'challenges_created'. 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 12 
Invalid column name 'challenges_created'.

Answer (score 1):

```
select C.Hacker_id, H.Name, count(challenge_id)
from Hackers H Inner Join Challenges C
ON H.Hacker_Id = C.Hacker_Id
group by C.Hacker_Id, H.Name
having count(challenge_id) not in (select x.ChallengeCount from (  
    select C.Hacker_id, H.Name, count(challenge_id) as ChallengeCount
    from Hackers H Inner Join Challenges C
    ON H.Hacker_Id = C.Hacker_Id
    group by C.Hacker_Id, H.Name
 ) x
where x.ChallengeCount <> (select top 1 count(challenge_id) from Challenges group by hacker_Id order by 1 desc) 
group by x.ChallengeCount
having count(x.challengecount) > 1)
order by 3 desc, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH TEMP AS
(

SELECT H.HACKER_ID AS HID,
 H.NAME AS HNAME, 
COUNT(C.CHALLENGE_ID) AS CNT 
FROM HACKERS 
JOIN CHALLENGES C     
ON H.HACKER_ID=C.HACKER_ID 
GROUP BY H.HACKER_ID,H.NAME   
)

SELECT * FROM TEMP 
WHERE CNT IN
(   SELECT CNT FROM TEMP   count challenges
    GROUP BY CNT
    HAVING COUNT(CNT)=1 
) OR CNT=(SELECT MAX(CNT) FROM TEMP)  
ORDER BY CNT DESC,HID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT c.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS cnt 
FROM Hackers h, Challenges c
where h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id, h.name 
HAVING
count(c.challenge_id) = (SELECT max(COUNT(c1.challenge_id)) FROM Challenges c1 
       GROUP BY c1.hacker_id)
OR
count(c.challenge_id) NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.challenge_id) FROM Challenges c2 
            GROUP BY c2.hacker_id 
            HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id)
ORDER BY cnt DESC, c.hacker_id;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This not so complex logic might be easier to understand;

```
    WITH now AS (SELECT hacker_id AS hi, COUNT(*) AS nmbr, 
                COUNT(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) AS ccnt
                FROM challenges
                GROUP BY hacker_id)
   SELECT n.hi, h.name, n.nmbr
   FROM now AS n, hackers AS h
   WHERE (n.nmbr = (SELECT MAX(nmbr) FROM now) OR n.ccnt = 1)
   AND n.hi = h.hacker_id
   ORDER BY n.nmbr DESC, n.hi
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ch.hacker_id,h.name,count(ch.challenge_id) as challenges_created
from hackers h
join
challenges  ch
on 
h.hacker_id=ch.hacker_id
group by ch.hacker_id,h.name
having count(ch.challenge_id)in (select max(a.cnt) from (select count(challenge_id) as cnt from challenges group by hacker_id)a)

union 
select ch.hacker_id,h.name,count(ch.challenge_id) as challenges_created
from hackers h
join
challenges  ch
on 
h.hacker_id=ch.hacker_id
group by ch.hacker_id,h.name
having count(ch.challenge_id)IN(select c.chlng from (select b.chlng, count(*) as cnt  from (select hacker_id,count(challenge_id) as chlng from challenges group by hacker_id)b group by b.chlng) c where c.cnt=1)

order by challenges_created desc, ch.hacker_id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
  select a.hacker_id,a.name,count(b.challenge_id) as challange,COUNT(COUNT(b.challenge_id)) OVER(PARTITION BY COUNT(b.challenge_id)) as rank_
    from Hackers as a inner join Challenges as b
    on a.hacker_id = b.hacker_id
    group by a.hacker_id,a.name
) select hacker_id,name,challange from cte
where rank_>1 and challange=(select max(challange) from cte) or rank_ =1
order by challange desc,hacker_id
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to the question

```
with cte as
(
select h.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.challenge_id) counts
from hackers h inner join challenges c on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
group by  h.hacker_id, h.name
)
select
a.hacker_id, a.name, a.counts
from
cte a
inner join (select count(1) rankie, counts from cte b group by counts) b on a.counts= b.counts
cross join ( select max(counts) maxCount from cte) c
where 1=1
and (a.counts < c.maxCount
and rankie <=1)
or a.counts = c.maxCount
order by a.counts desc, a.hacker_id desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Keep in mind that this question is five years old and this answer doesn't explain the error in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you can't refer to field aliases in the `HAVING` clause
Instead use

```
COUNT(Challeneges.challenge_id)
```

You can also try this

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, 
       h.name, 
       COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS challenge_count
FROM Hackers h
JOIN Challenges c ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING challenge_count = 
    (SELECT COUNT(challenge_id) AS count_max
     FROM Challenges
     GROUP BY hacker_id 
     ORDER BY count_max DESC limit 1)
OR challenge_count IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT c_compare AS c_unique
     FROM (SELECT h2.hacker_id, 
                  h2.name, 
                  COUNT(challenge_id) AS c_compare
           FROM Hackers h2
           JOIN Challenges c ON c.hacker_id = h2.hacker_id
           GROUP BY h2.hacker_id, h2.name) counts
     GROUP BY c_compare
     HAVING COUNT(c_compare) = 1)
ORDER BY challenge_count DESC, h.hacker_id;
```

In my code I haven't use aliases thus it is not showing any errors.

Comment: It'd be more useful to point out a misunderstand of the OP that causes this specific error rather than simply "try this, it may or may not work and you'll have no idea why".  I would personally have no faith to try your answer specifically because it contains zero explanation as to why it would work.

Comment: Thank you for your view I am new to stack overflow so I'll keep that in mind and it was helpfully @DanRayson

Comment: I just noticed that this question has already been answered anyway and was just an obvious typing error.  Please try answering new questions rather than already answered and solved old questions.  You'll get more reputation that way too, so it's better for you and everyone else.

Comment: Thank you so much.